# Make instance of class on existing variable

Tags: c++, class, instance

How i can make c++ instance on existing variable
This is my header:

```
#ifndef PERSON_H_
#define  PERSON_H_
class Person{
private:
  std::string name = "default";
public:
 void setName(std::string name);
 }
 #endif
```

This is my person.cpp

```
#include "person.h";
void setName(std::string name){
    this->name=name;
  }
```

And my main cpp file

```
 #include <iostream>
 int main(){
 Person p;
 p.setName("Jack");
 //so person now have name Jack.
 //here is my problem
 p=new Person;
 //get error.So how i can on variable p make new instance of Person for return all to default values
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: @codelife There's no need to add tags to the title.

Answer (score 1):

`new` gives you a pointer to a new instance of `Person`. A HolyBlackCat pointed out, you are not using a pointer here. So either use `p = Person()` or go with pointers from the very beginning with `Person *p = new Person()`. However, in this case, I really do not see any need for pointers.

Comment: It's not about pointers, but about storage duration and allocation type.

Answer (score 0):

`p = Person();`. In most cases `p = {};` will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Person* p = new Person(); If you do want to make a new instance use pointer of type Person which will point to the memory address allotted by the new operator. Do whatever operation you want to perform. Since you are using new, make sure to use a delete operator to prevent memory leaks.delete p; delete will basically delete the value at the address pointed by p and assign a nullptr to it so that it doesn't become a dangling pointer. Then again if you want to assign new instance you can use the new operator. Now will p point to a different memory location which is the address of the new object.

-`Person *p = new Person();`
`//perform operations`
`delete p;`
`p = new Person();`

Comment: Would you consider tidying this up a bit? There's a Preview pane where you can see the post before you submit it, and an Edit feature where you can make fixes afterwards.

Comment: Don't recommend naked `new` & `delete` in 2020. That's more than two decades out of date.